# SQL Server query to check if date has the same digit

Tags: sql, sql-server

case statement to validate if date column is all the same number number (ie. 1s, 2s, etc)

```
DECLARE @opendate varchar 
SET opendate = '11111111' 

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN opendate LIKE '^([0-9a-z])\1+$')
            THEN 'invalid' 
    END AS date
```

Comment: I suspect you are not storing the date as a DATE .   Sample data and desired would be helpful.

Comment: Why would you want to validate if someone entered the date 11 November 1111 (as that's the *only* date that can have all the same digits)? `'22222222'` or, presumably, `2222-22-22` isn't a valid date; there aren't 22 months in the year.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use! Otherwise you'll end up with a `varchar` variable of **exactly ONE character** in length !

Comment: Just because this is closed doesn't mean you can't mark an existing answer as the answer 
 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
declare @opendate varchar(50)
set @opendate = '11111111111' 
select @opendate, case when patindex('%[^'+left(@opendate,1)+']%',@opendate) = 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bdf3fc417ed82a0538ee4c98190d2aa9)

Answer (score 1):

Since your date can be virtually any string, the repeating digits is only part of the problem.

You should use `try_convert()` and also test the year to ensure it is within a reasonable range

**Example**

```
-- Create some Sample Data for demonstrative purposes.
;with cte as (
 Select SomeDateCol=replicate(N,8)
  From  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0))v(N)
 Union All
 Select SomeDateCol
  From  (values ('19980499'),('19991216'),('25252525'))v(SomeDateCol)
)
Select *
      ,case when try_convert(date,SomeDateCol) is null 
              or year(try_convert(date,SomeDateCol)) not between 1900 and 2525
            then 'Invalid'
            else 'Valid'
       end
 From  cte
```

**Results**

```
SomeDateCol (No column name)
11111111    Invalid
22222222    Invalid
33333333    Invalid
44444444    Invalid
55555555    Invalid
66666666    Invalid
77777777    Invalid
88888888    Invalid
99999999    Invalid
00000000    Invalid
19980499    Invalid
19991216    Valid
25252525    Invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer works for any string length up to 12 characters.

```
;with max_number_seq_length_cte as (
    select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) v(N))
select v.string, case when count(distinct substring(v.string, fn.n, 1))=1 then 'Invalid'
                      else 'Valid' end new_col
from (values ('1111111'),
             ('444444444'),
             ('4455158')) v(string)
     cross apply (select n 
                  from max_number_seq_length_cte
                  where n<=len(v.string)) fn
group by v.string;
```

```
string      new_col
1111111     Invalid
444444444   Invalid
4455158     Valid
```